# YUI ScrollView Paging by Page numbers

Tags: yui, scrollview

I am trying to use the `YUI ScrollView` with paging but I do not want to use the "previous + next" button. Instead I would like a to have a container with links to each page.

Is it possible to skip to a specific page of `ScrollView` on a button/link click.

Something like

```
scrollView.pages.ScrollToPage(3);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. You can find the documentation [here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/scrollview/index.html#paginator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation explains, there is a `scrollTo` method in the ScrollViewPaginator plugin: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Plugin.ScrollViewPaginator.html#method_scrollTo.

You just need to write something like `scrollview.pages.scrollTo(3, 0.6, "ease-in");`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was trying the same thing, but I did not notice the case. It was scrollView instead of scrollview.